# Combining ExpressionEngine Matrix Fields

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, matrix, expressionengine

Is there anyway to combine rows inside of two separate Matrix fields?

I have a gallery where I have pictures and videos. Right now I have two matrix fields, photo and video with a file cell type and a text cell type. My gallery displays photos first, than videos. Is there any way to combine these field types so the order of the photos and videos are combined?

Comment: I had most of an answer written up when I realized I might have been misreading your question. Are you looking to combine these two fields permanently into one Matrix field in EE? Or simply combine the *contents* of these two fields when displaying them on the front-end?

Comment: Combining the contents of the two fields when display on the front-end.

Comment: I guess my next question then would be: why not just combine these fields? Is there a reason they have to be separate?

Comment: They have two seperate media types. One field is an image source, the next field is a video link. So I need to combine two data types, a file and a text field. I was thinking of having two columns (image and text) and just leaving one or the other blank depending..

Comment: I'd say that's a wiser route, and less confusing for your client as well. You could label them as "Upload an image" for the first column, then "OR Paste-in a video link" for the second. Commingling the two fields would require either doing  bunch of PHP in your template, or doing some custom queries with the Query module.

Comment: yep thats what I thought too - put that answer at the bottom and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a single Matrix field for both photo and video. You could label the columns as "Upload an image" for the first column, then "OR Paste-in a video link" for the second.

Commingling the two fields during the template rendering would require either doing bunch of PHP in your template, or doing some custom queries with the Query module.